# Does rspec access the database when tests are run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using rspec-rails to test a controller in my rails application. In one instance, I'm creating new objects to test that they're properly assigned to instance variables.

```
describe MainController do
    describe "GET #index" do
        it "properly assigns a colored ball" do
            ball1 = Ball.create(color: 'red')
            get :index
            expect(assigns(:red_balls)).to eq([ball1])
        end
    end
end
```

When I run the test, does rspec access the database to create ball1 and then delete it once the test is run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the snippet in your question, Yes `Rspec` access the DB configured as test in the `database.yml` file, if you want to clean out the DB/Records created by `Rspec` you can use the [database_cleaner gem](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) you can configure it as you deem fit.

e.g:

add `gem database_cleaner` to your `Gemfile`

and the below to your `spec_helper.rb` file as specified by the `database_cleaner` documentation:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

Then `database_cleaner` would truncate the tables in the `test db` and leave them in a pristine state

Answer (score 0):

To add to what bjhaid said above - Rspec should only be accessing you 'test' database. Check out the config/database.yml to see the configuration of your different databases.

So you do not have to worry about things in your development or production databases interfering with your testing database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, RSpec allows your database calls to go through, but with the rspec-rails gem under the default configuration, it will execute each test within a database transaction and will roll back that transaction at the end of each example with no action required on your part.  No additional gem is required.  See https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions.